# DataNucleus.Persistence - Property javax.jdo.option.spi.ResourceName unknown

Tags: java, persistence, jdo, datanucleus

I'm using Java Data Objects (JDO) to persist custom Java classes. This works fine, but my log is getting flooded by the following info message when I'm getting or saving objects from/to the store:

> DataNucleus.Persistence - Property javax.jdo.option.spi.ResourceName unknown - will be ignored

Googling this message brings up some results, but those aren't specific to getting rid of this message. I hope you guys can help! Below you'll find the content of my `jdo.properties` file:

```
javax.jdo.PersistenceManagerFactoryClass=org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory
javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL=jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/dbName
javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName=userName
javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword=password
datanucleus.autoCreateSchema=true
datanucleus.autoCreateTables=true
datanucleus.autoCreateColumns=true
datanucleus.PersistenceUnitName=MyPersistenceUnit
datanucleus.query.jdoql.allowAll=true
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question (perhaps it will be useful for somebody):

I had an older initialization of a `PersistenceManagerFactory` instance using

```
PersistenceManagerFactory pmfInstance = JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory("transactions-optional");
```

which ignored my *jdo.properties* file. Changing the code to

```
PersistenceManagerFactory pmfInstance = JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory("jdo.properties");
```

solves this problem.

Comment: As it should ignore your jdo.properties ... you passed in a "persistence-unit" name, rather than a file name ... when you wanted to use some properties in a file.

Comment: Yes, you're totally right! I just overlooked that initialization in one of my classes.

Answer (score 0):

JDOHelper when creating a PMF (incorrectly) adds some properties of its own into what is passed to the implementations constructor. All recent versions of DataNucleus don't output that log message and ignore the property. All earlier versions output the log message and ignore the property.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however I'm experiencing the same message using the current version (3.0.5).